# setValueAt in TableModel always gets a string

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable that contains different object types in one of its column. Each of the type has its own renderer and editor (getDefaultRenderer(Number.class), my own Date renderer/editor etc.).

However method `setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col)` in my table model (I override DefaultTableModel) always has String as `value`. So despite different editors I can't update rows without parsing the String which is not a good idea, because my table should easily handle additional object types in the future.

`getValueAt(int row, int col)` doesn't convert object to Strings. I checked it out. What's the reason of this behaviour?

EDIT: Code below. Only Boolean cell editor seems to work right.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class Tabela {

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame fr = new JFrame("tabela");
    fr.setSize(600, 400);
    fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // custom renderer and editor for Date
    final DateCellEditor dateEditor = new DateCellEditor();
    final DateCellRenderer dateRenderer = new DateCellRenderer();

    final TableModel model = new TableModel();
    JTable table = new JTable(model){
        public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int col){
            if (model.getValueAt(row, col) instanceof Boolean)
                return getDefaultEditor(Boolean.class);
            else if (model.getValueAt(row, col) instanceof Number)
                return getDefaultEditor(model.getValueAt(row, col).getClass());
            else if (model.getValueAt(row, col) instanceof Date)
                return dateEditor;
            else return getDefaultEditor(Object.class);
        }

        public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int col){
            if (model.getValueAt(row, col) instanceof Boolean)
                return getDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class);
            else if (model.getValueAt(row, col) instanceof Number)
                return getDefaultRenderer(model.getValueAt(row, col).getClass());
            else if (model.getValueAt(row, col) instanceof Date)
                return dateRenderer;
            else 
                return getDefaultRenderer(Object.class);
        }
    };
    JScrollPane sc = new JScrollPane(table);
    fr.getContentPane().add(sc);
    fr.setVisible(true);    
}

public static class TableModel extends DefaultTableModel{
    // data in first column
    private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    // data in second column - can by any object
    private ArrayList<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public TableModel(){
      // insert example data
        names.add("string value");
        values.add("some string");
        names.add("number value");
        values.add(new Integer(12345));
        names.add("Boolean value");
        values.add(new Boolean(false));
        names.add("Double value");
        values.add(new Double(10.5));
        names.add("Date object");
        values.add(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col){
        values.set(row, value);
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col){
        if (col==0)
            return names.get(row) + " ["+values.get(row).getClass().getSimpleName()+"]";
        else return values.get(row); 
    }

    public int getRowCount(){
        if (values==null) return 0;
        else return values.size();
    }

    public int getColumnCount(){
        return 2;
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col){
        return col==1; // only column 2 is editable
    }

    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col){
        switch(col){
        case 0:
            return String.class;
        default:
            return Object.class;
        }
    }

}

// My own renderer and editor for Date type
protected static class DateCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{
    private static DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-y HH:mm:ss");

    public static void setDateFormat(String f){
        format = new SimpleDateFormat(f);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent (JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)    
    {       
            if (value instanceof Date){
                value = format.format(value);
            }
            else if(value instanceof Calendar)    
            {    
                    Calendar dateValue = (Calendar) value;    
                    value = format.format(dateValue.getTime());  
            } 
            Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column); 
            if (c instanceof JComponent){
                JComponent jc = (JComponent) c;
                jc.setToolTipText("dd-MM-y HH:mm:ss");
            }
            return c;
    }    
}

protected static class DateCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor{
    private static DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-y HH:mm:ss");
    private JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(format);

    public DateCellEditor(){
        super(new JFormattedTextField(format));
    }

    public void setDateFormat(String f){
        format = new SimpleDateFormat(f);
        textField = new JFormattedTextField(format);
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent (JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)    
    {       System.out.println("editor: "+value.getClass());
            if (value instanceof Date){
                value = format.format(value);
            }
            else if(value instanceof Calendar)    
            {    
                    Calendar dateValue = (Calendar) value;    
                    value = format.format(dateValue.getTime());  
            } 
            return super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);    
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: I can think of a couple possible reasons, but they are nothing more then guesses, can you provide a runnable example that demonstrates your problem

Comment: something wrong with the code (most probably of an editor) you are not showing ...

Comment: several thingies wrong: a) dont' interfere with the editor lookup, intstead implement the model return the columnclass correctly b) the appropriate listener to register with a formattedTextField is a propertyChangeListener for its value property (vs. an ActionListener as is registered by super) c) unrelated: you are mixing coordinates in getCellEditor(row, column) the param indices are in view coordinates while accessing the model must be done in model coordinates

Comment: ahh .. overlooked your first sentence, so my a) in the comment doesn't apply and c becomes related ;-) And don't forget to check the value against null, as @Mad already mentioned.

Comment: see one of intuitive ways [Complex Table Cell Rendering Made Simple in Java Net](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/08/21/complex-table-cell-rendering.html), not sure if is there (EachRow)TableCellEditor, but Renderer is good described

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From you code example there are (immediately) a number of things of concern.

Firstly, there shouldn't be any need to override the `getCellEditor` and `getCellRenderer` methods of `JTable`.

The biggest issues I would have with the way you've done this is what if the value from the model is `null`?

You can modify the cell editor and render for a given `Class` by using the `setDefaultEditor(Class, TableCellEditor)` and `setDefaultRenderer(Class, TableCellRenderer)` methods instead.

From your table model, you should be returning all the appropriate `Class` types of the required column (from `getColumnClass`).  The assumption here is that a given column has the same type of `Class` value.

However, the reason for your problem is in the editor.

If the example editor is anything to go by, you are extending from `DefaultCellEditor`, which simply uses a `JTextField` as it's editor.  This means that `getCellEditorValue` is going to return to `String`, hence the reason your `setValueAt` method is passed a `String` value.

There are a number of options.

1. You could devise a better `TableCellEditor` which used more appropriate editors (such as a `JSpinner` or `JCheckBox`)
2. You could override the `getCellEditorValue` to convert the `String` value from the default editor into a more appropriate `Object` type.

I prefer option 1 as it represents the underlying data in a form and editor that it is suited for and takes a lot of the mess out of dealing with bad parsing.

I would take a close look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and pay close attention to the sections of custom editors

Comment: how can I return all appropriate Class types from getColumnClass? They depend on a given row (multiple class types in the same column).

Comment: As I said, JTable assumes that a column of data is the same class, its JTable, not JSpreadSheet

Answer (score 1):

The clean-up the confusion I might have spread in my comments: if you have values with different classes in one column

- model.getColumnClass must return the common super of all those values, which often would be Object.class
- the way to implement per-row renderers/editors is indeed overriding table.getCellRenderer(row, column)

Some snippets

```
// override in JTable
@Override
public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column) {
    // use the per-column renderer if available
    TableColumn tableColumn = getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
    TableCellRenderer renderer = tableColumn.getCellRenderer();
    // if the column didn't provide a renderer and has type Object.class
    if (renderer == null && Object.class.equals(getColumnClass(column))) {
        Object value = getValueAt(row, column);
        if (value != null) {
            renderer = getDefaultRenderer(value.getClass());
        }
    }
    if (renderer == null) {
        // shouldn't happen, but fixing super bug
        renderer = getDefaultRenderer(Object.class);
    }
    return renderer;
}
```

Comment: please to see my deleted post here

Answer (score 0):

The returned object can't be a string for many reason:

- formatting (12345 ==> 1 234, date, float...)
- sorting

An Object to String converter is easy to do, but a String to Object will be very difficult to write in a generic way.